# Can AWS CodeBuild output unzipped artifacts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

So I have a CodeBuild process, the output of which I want to be a nested Cloudformation stack and a zipped Lambda deployable, both pushed to an S3 bucket.

I can do the outputting process via `pip install awscli` and then `aws s3 cp #{stuff}` in `buildspec.yml`, but on reading the CodeBuild docs it feels like I should really be using `OutputArtifacts` for this bit.

So .. I remove the above `awscli` stuff, add an `OutputArtifacts` block to the `CodeBuild` stage of my code pipeline, and add an `artifacts` block to  `buildspec.yml`.

Everything works fine, CodeBuild dumps the output artifacts to S3 .. but the problem is they are zipped. That's no good because I need another "master" CF stack to be able to reference the generated / output CF template as a nested stack via an S3 bucket/key reference.

And when I look in the CodeBuild docs I can't find any reference to outputting unzipped artifacts.

Any thoughts on how I might achieve this ? Should I just stick with `awscli` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating or updating your CodeBuild Project, set the ProjectArtifact type to S3 and packaging to none as explained in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/APIReference/API_ProjectArtifacts.html#CodeBuild-Type-ProjectArtifacts-packaging.

However, the above step will only work when you use CodeBuild as a standalone. When CodeBuild is used in the context of CodePipeline, your pipeline defines the source and artifact details. Your best option in this case is using awscli copy to s3 during the build step of the pipeline.